# Flutter: When i pass parameter to get data from api to make a listview but data not coming?

Tags: flutter, api, parameters

I have implemented an API for my subcategory page. I have to pass `cat_id` parameter to get data from APIbut data is not coming, showing `HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = https://newbharatbiz.in/admin/upload/banner/1542696279`. I want to show a Listview . Below I have attached the subcategory page class.

SubCategoryPage:

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:newbharatbiz/Model%20Class/CatWiseServiceList.dart';
    import 'package:newbharatbiz/Screens/HomePage.dart';
    
    final String ServiceAPI =
        "https://newbharatbiz.in/mobile_api/v4/services_list.php";
    
    class SubCategoryPage extends StatelessWidget {
      final String id;
    
      const SubCategoryPage({
        Key? key,
        required this.id,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      Future<List<dynamic>> fetchcatwiselist() async {
        var params = {
          "cat_id": id,
        };
    
        var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ServiceAPI),
            body: json.encode(params)
            ,headers: {
              HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
            });
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
          // then parse the JSON.
          //  return CatwiseServiceModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
          return json.decode(response.body)['services'];
        } else {
          // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
          // then throw an exception.
          throw Exception('Failed to load album');
        }
      }
    
    
      String service_name(dynamic user) {
        return user['service_name'];
      }
    
      String image(dynamic user) {
        return user['image'];
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text('All Services'),
              leading: new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(
                        context, true); // It worked for me instead of above line
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                    future: fetchcatwiselist(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        print((snapshot.data));
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Card(
                              //  <-- Card widget
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: Image.network(
                                    "https://newbharatbiz.in/admin/upload/services/min_image/" +
                                        snapshot.data[index]['image'],
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                title: Text(service_name(snapshot.data[index]),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }
                      return const Center(
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 16,
                          height: 16,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            strokeWidth: 2,
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blue),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    ),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try run your API using testing API tool? It works?

Comment: yes it works. i checked it on postman.

Comment: where you call this API?

Comment: you can see my api is above StatelessWidget and also you can check

Comment: is it the php file?

Comment: https://newbharatbiz.in/mobile_api/v4/services_list.php

Comment: you can also check api and responses(parameter you can put (cat_id))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242873/discussion-between-debendra-and-john-joe).